# Why use a special function to generate pseudo-random numbers in Pollard rho factorization?

Tags: function, factorization

I've been getting myself acquainted with the Pollard Rho factorization from [this page](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/classes/doku.php/pollard_rho_tutorial).

I think I understand almost everything there, but one thing I'm confused about – the fact that it uses `f(x) = x^2 + a mod N` to generate pseudo-random numbers for checking.

My question is, why can't we simply have a random number generator give us some two random numbers *(x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>j</sub>)* each time, where *x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>j</sub> < N*? 
Why use this function `f(x)`?

Comment: @kazik1616 pseudo-random numbers*

Comment: since it's cheap, maybe for performance reasons

Answer (score 1):

The particular random number generator doesn't matter. Pollard in his [original paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-f11/www/lectures/lect1122_Pollard.pdf) describing the algorithm says "Other polynomials of degree ≥ 2 and other starting values can be used." Brent [says](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb051i.pdf) "The choice of a (pseudo-) random *u* ∈ [0,1) is not essential; it merely makes the average-case analysis tractable. Pollard and Brent [describe](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/linglong/Math690ZS05/8thFermatnumber.pdf) the use of a function other than *x*<sup>2</sup> + *c* to factor 2<sup>2<sup>8</sup></sup> + 1. The advantage of the *x*<sup>2</sup> + *c* method is that it is simple to implement and gives a family of polynomials, making it easy to switch to another one if the first doesn't work.